# writing filenames into an array in Python

Tags: arrays, list, append

I read the files in a directory using glob, and then I rename each file to something more legible for my purposes using os.rename.

```
for file_name in glob.glob(path+'*.txt'):
newfilename = 'run'+str(i)+'.csv'       # rename filenames to something more readable
os.rename(file_name,path + newfilename)  #put r before path if error ="(unicode error) ‘unicodeescape’ codec can’t decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"
```

When I try to write the each new file created into an array (a list) previously intialized to :

```
filelist=[];
```

using

```
filelist.append(i)=newfilename
```

I get the following error: "SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call"

If I just try to add the file to the filelst array using indeces, ie, filelist[i]=newfilename, I then get an index out of range error.

How do I do create this list of renamed filenames "on the fly"?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..so I finally understood that append wants to "append the "thing" to the list, as opposed to "append the thing at index i to the list" like I was trying to do originally.

So the correct way to use append is:

```
filelist.append(newfilename)
```